# iPhone 6 volume too loud on Bluetooth headphones

Tags: iphone, audio, ipod-touch, bluetooth, headphones

I have insomnia and use the sound therapy app Digipill to help me fall asleep. I've started to use its sounds through Bluetooth headphones, but I've come across an issue. A low setting on the iPhone's volume slider (~20%) is still insanely loud (hurts my ears) and if I slide the volume down to what should be the lowest setting then there is no sound whatsoever.

So how can I get sound through my BT headphones at a not-deafening volume?

**Things I've tried, not necessarily in this order:**

1. about 30 different brands/models of bluetooth headphones. From Best Buy legit high dollar brand name as well as Amazon/eBay cheap imports. All do the same thing.
2. Music settings: EQ trying each type of setting option, Volume Limit specifying a Max volume that's as low as possible, Sound Check on/of. I've done every possible combination with no effect on the volume.
3. Returned my new iPhone and got a replacement NEW iPhone, not refurbished. So this is not isolated to just my iPhone or another refurbed iPhone.
4. Also have tried on an iPad 2nd generation, iPad Air, iPad Pro, iPad Mini 4... pretty much if you know me & have an Apple product I was trying it to see if it had the same issues.
5. Downloaded/purchased the app on craigslist's iPod Touch & synched quite a few of these bluetooth headphones. Same issues, no change.
6. In Settings used the "disability section" Accessibility's Hearing options: Mono Audio, Noise Cancellation, Hearing Devices and doing Hearing Aid Mode "on".
7. ONLY THING THAT HAS HELPED is in the Accessibility shifting the audio balance to 75% in one ear & NOT using that side of the headphones, **NOT A VIABLE SOLUTION** since I am using the hypnotherapy app to cover up noise & aide me in falling back asleep.

[image: Playing]
[image: Not playing]

Comment: I assume you've tried cycling through play/pause? It's unclear because the image with "Sound playing" is paused and the image with "no sound playing" is not paused. Comment back `@owlswipe` and I'd be happy to try to help more!

Comment: Also, is the sound only deafening from the Digipill app, or is music played through the Music app deafening as well? Basically, is this a problem with Digipill audio or with all audio?

Comment: Sorry I paused it since I couldn't hear anything. I've tried cycling through but haven't seen any change in the volume.

Comment: Also while in the music app it functions fine as long as I am using the "volume limit" option. I believe that is due to it being an music app while my DigiPill is an audio app or possibly not even specified as a type of app. I'm not sure how the apps/classification/developing works.

Comment: Sounds like a weird bug. Was Apple support really not able to fix it?

Comment: Also try turning the volume down from the BT headphones themselves?